# Is it eficient to merge similar data objects into single table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, entity-relationship

I need to store data a lot of similar data about my system of questions and the answer such as voting, following, bookmarks, etc.

In example of voting, what is the best table layout for storing votes for questions, answers, and posts?

1. Store the votes separately, that is, 3 tables are obtained: UserQuestionVotes, UserAnswerVotes and UserPostVotes
2. Store votes in one table:
   UserVotes (id, user_id, item_id, item_type, vote), 
   while: item_id and item_type is the id and type of the question, answer or post, vote = -1/1

If I go the first way, I will have at least 9 tables.
And if I go the second way, that is, all the data in one heap, so in the future, when filling out the table, it will work more slowly.

Which way in my case eficient?

Comment: Time to follow a published academic textbook on information modelling, the relational model & DB design & querying. (Manuals for languages & tools to record & use designs are not such textbooks.) (Nor are wiki articles or web posts.) Dozens of published academic information modeling & DB design textbooks are online free in pdf. stanford.edu has a free online course. (But asking for resources outside SO is off-topic.) PS Don't ask us to rewrite a textbook with a bespoke tutorial. Follow one & ask a specific question about where you are stuck.

Comment: There's no such thing as "better"/"best" in engineering unless you define it. Also unfortunately all reasonable practical definitions require a ridiculous amount of experience with a ridiculous number of factors that interact with chaotic sensitivity to details. Make straightforward designs. When you demonstrate via measurement that a design and all alternatives you can think of have problems (whatever that means at the time), then ask a very specific question. Which should also define "better"/"best". [Strategy for “Which is better” questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204461/266284)

Comment: Hi @philipxy Thanks for the answer, and I do not ask anyone to order a tutorial. It was enough for me that from your own experience you figured out which option is more effective in terms of performance.

Comment: Try both.  Use it as a learning experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for my *opinion,* I would pick door #1.  Questions, Answers, and Posts are all separate, albeit related, "things."  And, each of these "things" happen to also have "votes" associated with them ... but, really, a "vote" is not a "thing."

A "vote for a question" is tightly associated with "the question."  "A vote for ..." anything else is the same.  So now I start thinking about the queries I'm most likely to actually write.  I'm most likely to want to write queries that, say, count how many votes a particular question has ... and I don't really want to muddy-up that query and make it either "hard to write" or obliged to look through a bunch of records that are not "votes *for questions."*  The other types of votes wouldn't be relevant and I'd rather not have to filter them out.  (If I need to write a query to count "how many votes for anything has this user cast?", I could very easily write that regardless.)

That's my *opinion.*  (The database manager can take care of "efficiency" on its own.  Design your database so that the queries you need to write are easy and clear to *write.)*